# Does Windows automatically load files on the desktop?

Tags: windows-10, performance, superfetch

I thought I'd heard that Windows 10 automatically loads all files on the desktop to the RAM or at least loads them to the vram on startup, specifically through superfetch. I heard that this can slow down your pc's startup. However, I'm not seeing this anywhere. Is this true?

Comment: Can you share exactly what you heard?  Windows can automatically load files.  Does not mean it will load every file into memory

Comment: That is exactly what I heard. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desktop is provided as a convenience for the user. Typically it would contain shortcuts to frequently used applications. But Windows itself has no interest in what you put there. There are documented methods for running applications at startup, such as the startup folder. The desktop is not one of these methods. Applications may be loaded into memory by Superfetch. Superfetch has it's own methods and doesn't look at the desktop. Applications on the desktop may run at startup but it will not be because they are there.

The only thing on the desktop that is loaded into memory are the file icons, names, and what is needed to display them.

Comment: I think I must have misunderstood it loading the file icons. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, not per se.

[Superfetch](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/what-is-superfetch/) observes your apps use and then applies its algorithms to decide what to preload. If the icons on your Windows 10 desktop link to apps which you don't use, those apps will not be loaded.